# Is it possible to clear a TPaintBox without drawing over with a rectangle

Tags: delphi, canvas

I have a `TPaintBox` that I want to clear. But I still need the transparency, so drawing a rectangle is not a possibility. How can I clear it?

Comment: What type of canvas? The VCL `TCanvas` doesn't have transparency. That's typically handled by a transparent color, usually white.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a `TPaintBox` has no concept of being transparent. To give the impression of transparency you can prevent painting in the area you want to show through (show what is behind the `TPaintBox`).

In the sample below, I have a `TImage` with the landscape picture. On top of that, there is a `TPaintBox` which draws the cross of red lines. With `Button1` I toggle a `boolean` flag (`TimeToClear`) and call `PaintBox1.Invalidate;`

The `OnPaint` method:

```
procedure TForm26.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
// Simply exit to prevent any painting;
  if TimeToClear then Exit;

// Otherwise perform normal drawing
  with (Sender as TPaintBox).Canvas do
  begin
    Pen.Style := psSolid;
    Pen.Color := Vcl.Graphics.clRed;
    Pen.Width := 5;
    MoveTo(  0,  0);
    LineTo(105,105);
    MoveTo(105,  0);
    LineTo(  0,105);
  end;
end;
```

[image][image]